# Different axioms for Euclidean geometry and other bodies of knowledge

Tags: euclidean-geometry, foundations, axiomatic-geometry

I was reading about Hilbert's, Birkhoff's and Tarski's axioms of Euclidean geometry, and I am very curious to learn how do mathematicians know that these different axiom systems lead to the same "body of knowledge" (in this case, Euclidean geometry). Also, how do they know that every theorem of Euclidean geometry (or other field) can be proved with their system of axioms?

Comment: Marvin's article won an award https://www.maa.org/programs/maa-awards/writing-awards/old-and-new-results-in-the-foundations-of-elementary-plane-euclidean-and-non-euclidean-geometries    may be downloaded  from the middle of the page

Comment: @Will Jagy: Thank you so much for this reference!

Comment: Basically, the simplest approach is to derive from Axiom System 1 all the axioms of Axiom System 2, and vice versa.ù